# Concrete Methods in Interface Classes

Tags: php, class, oop, interface, abstract

I am building some classes (in PHP, although this question extends to other OOP languages as well) which hold information from a database.  As such, I want to create an Interface: "syncable".

```
interface syncable{
  protected function _pushToDB();
  protected function _pullFromDB();
}
```

The problem I am encountering is that I want "syncable" to also have a method which (probably) never changes and variable to go with:

```
protected $sync = 0;

public function sync(){
  if($this->sync == 0){
    // DB in sync with class; Do nothing.
  }
  if(this->sync == 1){
    $this->_pushToDB();
    $this->sync = 0;
  }
  if(this->sync == -1){
    $this->_pullFromDB();
    $this->sync = 0;
  }
}
```

As variables are changed in an implemented class, or the database is updated elsewhere, the $sync variable is updated to properly reflect the type of sync needed, then sync() can be called at some point which in turn calls the proper implemented method.  While _pushToDB() and _pullFromDB() are very specialized per class, sync() will remain constant between most, if not all, classes.

Since the classes implementing "syncable" such as "users", "foo", and "bar" have no real relation to "syncable" and may need to extend other classes, "syncable" should be an interface rather than an abstract class.

So my question is, what is the best way of accomplishing this?  Must I copy-paste my sync() function into every class which implements "syncable"?  Do I create an abstract class and hope no class which extends "syncable" ever needs to extend anything else?  (Since PHP and many OOP don't support multiple-inheritance)  Is there some other PHP solution which would better fit this situation?  Are there any generic OOP solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at `php traits`, you can create this traits and then use them whereever you want/need to use them, is a part of the multi-inheritance principle:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: Really no other answer for PHP.  Traits are in essence a bit of a work-around for lack of mulitple inheritance in PHP.

Comment: Yes, its a work-around, but i've been using them for quite a bit now and never got any trouble, and had a chance to centralize a lot of code without the need to inherit from a monster abstrac class :D

Comment: NOt saying it is a bad approach to use at all.  In fact, it is a quite useful bit of functionality in PHP that many are not aware of.  I should have maybe said this is PHP's (and other language with trait-like constructs) answer to multiple inheritence.

Comment: Yes it's not a very well-known feature, but as you say, its quite useful :)

Comment: So it appears a trait is similar to just doing a "include traitFile.php" - is that more or less what happens?  (ie: I *cannot* make a "sync" trait and "use" it inside the interface, correct?)

Comment: no, interfaces just are contracts, nothing concrete. The advantage of the traits are that they kinda "bond" with your class, so $this in your trait is the "host" that is currently using it.